# Make text selectable in html pages looking like iPhone forms

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

I am working on an application than needs to create pages looking like this:

- http://iui-js.appspot.com/samples/music/music.html#_usage

The problem I have is that, just like in the page linked above, the values are not selectable neither with iSafari nor with the desktop version of Safari.

I need to be able to select and copy the values (in the example page these are '2', '8' and '27').

I would be fine simply knowing why the above text is not selectable in the first place, as this would probably be enough to find a workaround solution.

Thanks everybody for the kind attention.

Comment: I don't see any numbers on the example page, selectable or otherwise.

Comment: Javascript is overriding the mouse events keeping you from selecting stuff. You could undoubtedly inject your own JS into the pages to defeat whatever the site's scripts are doing.

Comment: @Marta: when you load it the first time, it redirect to a different url; if you select it again it should load fine.
Otherwise go to Stats -> Usage 

@wkw: where do you see the javascript overriding the mouse events? Going through the DOM hierarchy with the webkit inspector I could not find any event listener redefined.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the problem is caused by the following option

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
```

Alternative options, for the same property, are `auto` and `text`.
Further documentation available on [Safari CSS reference page](https://web.archive.org/web/20100112004212/https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html)